# desired capabilities not recognized by appium

Tags: appium

My desired capabilities from code are like below:

```
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
    capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.VERSION, "4.4.2");
    capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_NAME,
        "Android");
    capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME,
        "Android emulator");
capabilities
        .setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.BROWSER_NAME, "Browser");
    try {
        driver = new AndroidDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"),
            capabilities);
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
driver.navigate().to("http://google.com");
```

My appium server debug info is showing below lines:

```
> info: --> POST /wd/hub/session {"desiredCapabilities":{"browserName":"Browser","platformName":"Android","version":"5.1.1","deviceName":"Android emulator"}}
> info: Client User-Agent string: Apache-HttpClient/4.3.3 (java 1.5)
> info: [debug] The following desired capabilities were provided, but not recognized by appium. They will be passed on to any other services running on this server. : version
```

Note: I have the AVD started with the same desired capabilities. Still it is showing the same message. And browser is opened in one of the already started AVD randomly.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Please change `capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.VERSION, "4.4.2");`

to `capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.VERSION, "1.1.0");`

Please verify that your simulator name is "Android emulator" and not something else.

Also I don't see APP_PACKAGE and APP_ACTIVITY capabilities.